# Want suggestions on choosing open source embedded BI tool

Tags: visualization, data

I need some suggestions from all group members regarding the open source reporting/dash-boarding tool which fulfills below specific requirements apart from some basic BI functionalities:
1. Can be embedded inside a web
2. Interactive (filters and one chart selection affecting other charts)
3. Able to give excel downloadable option for plotted data
4. Role based user access

You can suggest tools supporting all requirements or partial also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/) - it can do all mentioned stuff ( and even more, you can plug in R/python code), but its not open-sourced, though you can go for a free 1-user account.

I guess [tableau](https://www.tableau.com/) can do the same and also has "community" version, but im a fan of Power BI, so cant tell more about it.

If you need some custom, build-from-scratch solution, you can go for [Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) - fully build on R, fully open sourced and has free hosting option, can be embedded as an iframe ( will prolly look horrible), but fully customizable and can be tuned the way you want it to be.

Similar to Shiny, but with Python: [Dash](https://dash.plot.ly)